# Understanding difference between SQL statments

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I am confused on how 2 different SQL conditions would work. Suppose I have a table with 3 datetime columns named `price_timestamp_a`, `timestamp_a` and `original_timestamp_a` for product `a` and 3 datetime column pertaining to product `b` `price_timestamp_b`, `timestamp_b` and `original_timestamp_b`

I want to check for condition where `price_timestamp_a < timestamp_a < original_timestamp_a` is met or
`price_timestamp_b < timestamp_b < original_timestamp_b` is met. ut the last condition should be definelty met i.e. `cateogry <> cateogry_chunk`. to achieve this I wrote the following SQL is this correct?

```
where (price_timestamp_a < timestamp_a
and timestamp_a < original_timestamp_a)
or (price_timestamp_b < timestamp_b
and timestamp_b < original_timestamp_b)
and (cateogry <> cateogry_chunk)
```

How the results from SQL above differs with the results from SQL below:

```
where (price_timestamp_a < timestamp_a
and timestamp_b < timestamp_original_b)
or ((price_timestamp_b < timestamp_b
and timestamp_b < original_timestamp_b)
and (cateogry <> cateogry_chunk)
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SQL typically does 'AND' before 'OR'. Therefore `a AND b OR c` is equivalent to `(a AND b) OR c` where a AND b is evaluated first, then it checks whether that OR c is true. In contrast, `a AND (b OR c)` is different - it checks whether b OR c is true, and then checks this AND a. Also note that when writing SQL, I first determine the highest type of check (AND or OR) and then have rows/spacing clearly indicate the 'highest level' e.g., line 1 woult be `(a OR b)`, line 2 `AND (c or d or e)`, line 3 `AND (f)`

Comment: *"the results from SQL above differs with the results from SQL below"* The SQL below won't run, because the **parentheses are unbalanced**.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Should you use as below:

```
WHERE cateogry <> cateogry_chunk
AND (( price_timestamp_a < timestamp_a
        AND timestamp_b < timestamp_original_b)
      OR (price_timestamp_b < timestamp_b
        AND timestamp_b < original_timestamp_b)
)
```

If Equality is expected, I would use:

```
WHERE cateogry <> cateogry_chunk
AND ( timestamp_a BETWEEN price_timestamp_a AND timestamp_original_b
      OR timestamp_b BETWEEN price_timestamp_b AND original_timestamp_b 
)
```